# How to use BetterAuthorizationSample? - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, authentication, root

I am trying to use BetterAuthorizationSample rather then go the so called "malicious" way of using setuid in order to get root privileges.

Currently I am using AuthorizationCreate(); with BLAuthentication to have root access to changing some files, but I am somewhat irritated by the fact that I have to constantly enter my password in every time the app launches.

So I came across Apple's method of a HelperTool, and I just can't figure it out.

I've been working with Cocoa for a couple months now, but this is just out of my reach, yet I still need it. How would I implement this tool to do simple root-privileged tasks?

Is there a simpler way to use the concept of a HelperTool, so that my users can just enter their password once and it would grant root-privileges forever?

Comment: Just to get this out of the way: [BetterAuthorizationSample](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample/) is now part of the Legacy documentation library. Note when this question was asked. There may be a more modern solution than what BetterAuthorizationSample implements.

Answer (score 2):

The "modern" way to do a helper tool on Mac OS X is to ship it as part of your app, and [use the `ServiceManagement` framework to deploy it](http://blog.ideveloper.tv/designing-writing-and-deploying-a-privileged-helper-on-mac-os-x/). Your users enter their password once, when deploying the tool. That installs it as a `launchd` job; from then on you use [any launchd on-demand mechanism](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html%23//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.plist) to launch the helper and get it to do work for you.

Notice that the blog post linked above recommends that you protect subsequent invocations of the helper with an [Authorization Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html) escalation, to avoid having an arbitrary privilege escalation that anyone can use. This seems like it somewhat impacts the "users can just enter their password once" benefit, although you can use [`AuthorizationRightSet()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html) to create your app's authorization token in the policy database, so you can actually define whether users need to present passwords on first deployment.

The sample code from that post is [on GitHub](https://github.com/iamleeg/LogViewer), and demonstrates using `ServiceManagement` to deploy the helper tool and Authorization Services to control access to it.

Comment: I thought i'd chime in and just point out that none of this will work if you're sandboxing your main application. SMJobBless() will fail.  Last i heard from Quinn he was working on an updated example that is suited for developers wishing to ship sandboxed applications outside of the App Store but still be able to do this kind of functionality.