# How do I copy a file to a location that requires special privileges in Obj-C or C?

Tags: objective-c, privileges, file-manager

I'm well aware of Privileged Helper tools and the purpose and techniques for deploying them. I've also successfully created and installed them — yet I cannot find a single example that illustrates how to simply copy a file to a location that requires special privileges. I thought FSPathCopyObjectSync would permit me to achieve this, [although I discovered the method was deprecated, along with what appears to be every single file operation on Mac OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html).

Here's what I've found so far:

• [BetterAuthorizationSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#/legacy/mac/library/samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) (deprecated)

• [SMJobBless](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) (essentially does nothing)

• [Privileged Helper Example](https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/privilegedhelperexample/src/528347da75ef?at=tip) (doesn't install command line tool below)

This is the method in the example above:

```
if (pFilename)
{
    // Base command minus cert name and file namem is 76 characters, 1 for NULL
    char* valCodeSignCmd = 0;
    // asprintf allocates & never overflows
    if (asprintf(&valCodeSignCmd, "codesign -v -R=\"certificate leaf[subject.CN] = \\\"%s\\\" and anchor apple generic\" \"%s\"", kSigningCertCommonName, pFilename) != -1)
    {
        if (system(valCodeSignCmd) == 0)
        {
            // Passed codesign validation
            // OK to copy now - overwrite if present
            OSStatus fsret = FSPathCopyObjectSync(pFilename, "/usr/local/bin", toolName, NULL, kFSFileOperationOverwrite);
            if (fsret != noErr)
                success = false;
        }

        // Clean up
        free(valCodeSignCmd);

    }
    else
        success = false;
}
```

What in the name of Steve Jobs is going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use BetterAuthorizationSample? - Cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773880/how-to-use-betterauthorizationsample-cocoa)

Comment: No, because I mentioned already it won't work. Here's the [info](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html)